# Why isn't my Server Side Includes (SSI) working?

Tags: html, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, ssi

I'm making a website, that is on a Amazon EC2 Instance with Apache, I'm trying to get SSI to work/be enabled, I've uploaded the .htaccess file and the file I want to be included, etc. But the SSI is still not working.  Why doesn't my SSI work?

All of the files I uploaded are located at `/var/www/html`, if that helps!

My .htaccess file has `AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml` in it.

My include command in my index.html file: `<!--#include file="main_nav.shtml" -->`.

---

The main_nav.shtml:

```html
<!--Main Nav-->
<header>
 <nav>
  <div class="main_nav">
  <a id="second_nav_bar" href="">Contact Me!</a>
  <a id="second_nav_bar" href="">About Me</a>
  <a id="second_nav_bar" href="">Search my site</a>


 <!--
  <div id="searchbox_div">
   <form action="" id="searchbox">
    <input id="search_input" type="search" name="searchmysite" placeholder="Search my Site!">
    <input type="submit" value="Search!">
   </form>
  </div>
 -->


  </div>
  
  <div id="logo">
   <h1 id="logo_jeff">JEFF</h1>
   <h1 id="logo_arries">ARRIES</h1>
   <h1 id="logo_website">WEBSITE</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div id="main_nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a class="main_nav" href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Trips</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Politics</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pictures</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Computer</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Misc</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
</header>

<!-- End Main Nav-->
```

Here's my files on my computer (not serving the files) (just to give a visual of what my server looks like, see below):
[image]

And here's a terminal screenshot of my Amazon EC2 server (serving the files), showing the files and structure (see above):
[image]

---

**FYI. My website is at [jeffarries.com](http://www.jeffarries.com) if you want to view it live.**

**If you need any further information, feel free to ask!**

---

Update:
[image: Terminal]

---

Update 2:

Main_nav.shtml:

```html
<!--#include file="main_nav.shtml" -->

<!--Main Nav-->
<header>
 <nav>
  <div class="main_nav">
  <a id="second_nav_bar" href="">Contact Me!</a>
  <a id="second_nav_bar" href="">About Me</a>
  <a id="second_nav_bar" href="">Search my site</a>


 <!--
  <div id="searchbox_div">
   <form action="" id="searchbox">
    <input id="search_input" type="search" name="searchmysite" placeholder="Search my Site!">
    <input type="submit" value="Search!">
   </form>
  </div>
 -->


  </div>
  
  <div id="logo">
   <h1 id="logo_jeff">JEFF</h1>
   <h1 id="logo_arries">ARRIES</h1>
   <h1 id="logo_website">WEBSITE</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div id="main_nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a class="main_nav" href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Trips</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Politics</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pictures</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Computer</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Misc</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
</header>

<!-- End Main Nav-->
```

index.shtml:

```html
<head>
<title>Home | Jeff's Website</title>

<link href="styles/main_navigation.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/body.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="styles/main_content.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- Icon code -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="/website_icons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/website_icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/website_icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/website_icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="60x60" href="/website_icons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="/website_icons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="/website_icons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="/website_icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/website_icons/favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/website_icons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/website_icons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/website_icons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/website_icons/favicon-128.png" sizes="128x128" />
<meta name="application-name" content="&nbsp;"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/website_icons/mstile-144x144.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="/website_icons/mstile-70x70.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/website_icons/mstile-150x150.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="/website_icons/mstile-310x150.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/website_icons/mstile-310x310.png" />
<!-- End Icon code -->



<!-- Chatrify Script-->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var __ac = {};
    __ac.uid = "08c261285ca9db6acdaf945deef7cd7b";
    __ac.server = "secure.chatrify.com";

    (function() {
      var ac = document.createElement('script'); 
      ac.type = 'text/javascript'; 
      ac.async = true;
      ac.src = 'https://cdn.chatrify.com/go.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(ac, s);
    })();
 </script>


</head>


<body>
 
 
<!--#include file="main_nav.shtml" -->



<!-- Landing Beta Pop Up box -->

<div id="popup_div">
 <div id="popup_beta">
  <p id="popup_main_header">Welcome to my website!</p>
  <p id="popup_main_content">My site is currently under construction. &nbsp; I'm trying to get everything ready, working and online as soon as possible. &nbsp;But for the time being, there may be broken/grayed out links and random stuff that doesn't work properly. Thank you for your patience!</p>
  
  <a id="got_it_button"href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup_div');">Got it!</a>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- End Landing Beta Pop Up box -->

<!-- Pop Up Email Form-->
<div id="popup_email_form_div">
 <div id="popup_email_form_div_content">
  <p>Contact Form</p>
  <form method="post" action=""></form>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- End Pop Up Email Form-->



<!--Welcome to jeff's website-->

<div>
 <h2 id="welcome">Welcome to my Website!</h1>
 
 <a href="#here_you_can_learn">
 <img src="pictures/down_arrow.png" id="down_arrow"/>
 </a>
</div>

<!-- End Welcome to Jeff's website-->

<!--right side nav-->

<aside>
 <p>this is aside</p>

</aside>


<!--Main Content-->

<div id="main_content">
 <h2 id="here_you_can_learn">Here you can learn about me and my adventures!</h2>

<!--Most Frequently visited pages: on left side of page-->
 <div id="most_frequent">
  <p class="heading">Most frequently visted pages!</p>
  
  
  
  <a href="" class="show_more_link"><p class="show_more">Show More</p></a>

 </div>
 
<!--Recent Activity: on the right side of page-->
 <div id="recent_activity">
  <p class="heading">Recent Activity</p>


  <p class="content">test</p>


  <a href="" class="show_more_link"><p class="show_more">Show More</p></a>
 </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display = 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }

</script>


</body>
```

Screenshot of what my finder window looks like now: (not serving the files, but the same as the server)

[image: Finder]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

> ```
> AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
> ```

…tells Apache to look in `.shtml` files for SSI directives.

You have placed your SSI directive (`<!--#include file="main_nav.shtml" -->`) in a `.html` file instead of a `.shtml` file.

Comment: Put the `AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml` in the .htaccess file?  And it appears my SSI directive does have .shtml.

Comment: @JeffArries — `index.html` does not have `.shtml`. `main_nav.shtml` has `.shtml` but `main_nav.shtml` does not contain the SSI directive.

Comment: Ok, so I need to put that in the file I'm SSIing, and name the file requesting the SSI .shtml too? I have `AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml` already in my .htaccess file.

Comment: You need to put `<!--#include file="main_nav.shtml" -->` in the file the browser is directly requesting (you have done this, you put it in `index.html`). That file must have a `.shtml` file extension (you have not done this, you called the file `index.html`).

Comment: Ok, will fix and upload!

Comment: Uploaded, if you go to my site it isn't there (nav bar).

Comment: I get a DNS error. Did you delete the `index.html` file *from the server* so that you can be sure the browser isn't still requesting it?

Comment: No I didn't! Will do!  My website is also at 54.213.219.247 if that helps!

Comment: Deleted, still not showing navigation bar, now showing Amazon Linux AMI Test Page. See update on main post with screenshot of terminal.

Comment: I think the Amazon Linux AMI Test Page is showing up because I don't have a index.html page on my server. (now it's index.shtml)

Comment: Try now, was trying them with without the "s" on .shtml, but it didn't work.

Comment: Add `Options +Includes` to the htaccess

Comment: Did that, appears my site is back, but still no nav bar.  Where should I save my .htaccess file?  It's currently where my other site files are (i.e. index.shtml, main_nav.shtml), should I be storing it somewhere else?

Comment: Is the server set up to support htaccess at all? Stick `Redirect 302 / http://example.com/` in it and see if you get redirected.

Comment: It says "-bash: Redirect: command not found" See update 2 for what the server looks like, and my code. Gotta run, see ya later!

Comment: Bash? That sounds like you tried to execute it as a shell command. Did you put it in htaccess or did you try putting it an `exec` SSI directive?

Comment: I'm using SSH to access the server, I thought you meant try putting it in Terminal command line and see what happens, rereading, it looks like you meant put it in the .htaccess file, correct?  Does it need to be `Redirect 302 / http://jeffarries.com/` or should I do it as `Redirect 302 / http://example.com/` as you said?

Comment: The point is to test if htaccess is working at all, so it introduces a redirect to a test site. If you redirected back to jeffarries.com you'd creating an infinite loop, which wouldn't be a very useful test.

Comment: Tried, didn't do anything as you can see if you go to to the website.  P.S. my .htaccess file now has `AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
Options +Includes
Redirect 302 / http://example.com/` in it.

Comment: If it didn't do anything that that sounds like support for .htaccess hasn't been turned on in the main Apache configuration.

Comment: Then you need to turn on htaccess support in it.

Comment: How?  I don't know how to access or change it.

Comment: You need to [AllowOverrides](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) and the config files will probably be in /etc/httpd or /etc/apache or /etc/apache2

Comment: using `ls /etc/httpd` I got `conf  conf.d  conf.modules.d  logs  modules  run`, which one should I edit?

Comment: Well, one of those directories will include the file you need to edit (possibly the main configuration file as I assume you haven't set up virtual name hosting since you say you haven't touched it yet). There might also be a standard way to enable it for whatever Linux distro you are using (whatever it is, it does it differently to the ones I use which have a lot of stuff in modules that you symlink from mods-available/ to modes-enabled/). You'll need to restart the Apache service after you edit the config. (Note link in previous comment to the relevant bit of the Apache manual).

Comment: Ok, got to the file, part of it says `# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as`, I need to remove the "none" from "AllowOverride", right?

Comment: On the page you sent me it says "When this directive is set to None and AllowOverrideList is set to None .htaccess, files are completely ignored. In this case, the server will not even attempt to read .htaccess files in the filesystem."

Comment: I will change it to `AllowOverride all`

Comment: Changed, how do I restart the server?

Comment: I don't know how your Linux distribution manages services. At a guess `service httpd restart`

Comment: Ok, I used this handy tool called Google, anyway. My restart code was `sudo /sbin/service httpd restart`, it restarted fine, but it didn't seem to do anything on the website end.

Comment: side note: when I tried `/sbin/service httpd restart` I got `rm: cannot remove '/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid': Permission deniedLED]

rm: cannot remove '/var/lock/subsys/httpd': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid': Permission denied
Starting httpd: (13)Permission denied: AH00058: Error retrieving pid file /var/run/httpd/httpd.pid AH00059: Remove it before continuing if it is corrupted.
[FAILED]`, but when I tried what I said above I got `Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:   [  OK  ] `

Comment: Ran out of space, so does that mean it couldn't delete some of the configuration file, so some of my settings may still be the same?

Comment: You need to be root to restart the server

Comment: How do I get to root?

Comment: My files are at `/var/www/html` does that mean root would be `var`?

Comment: No, the user with the username root (entirely unrelated to the root directory or the document root) which is the superuser or main system administrator account.

Comment: Like when I log in and it says `[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-54 ~]$ `?

Comment: Yes, that means you are ec2-user and not root. You need to change user accounts. You might want to look at the `sudo` command (or `su`)

Comment: If I use `sudo /sbin/service httpd restart` it works fine, but if I remove the `sudo` I get the same error as I showed above.

Comment: That's expected. `sudo` makes you root for a command and you have to be root to restart the service.

Comment: What should I do?  I tried that and my website still doesn't show my site (much less the nav bar). If I look at the configuration file my changes are saved however.

Comment: I was editing the wrong part of the httpd.conf file, oops!  Now I get redirected to example.com, but if I remove that I get the Apache setup page as before.

Comment: Got it to work, holy cow! Check it out now!  It shows 10 of my nav bars! and an error "[an error occurred while processing this directive]"

Comment: I also changed `<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>` to `<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.shtml
</IfModule>`

Comment: I removed the `<!--#include file="main_nav.shtml" -->` from the main_nav.shtml, and now it works as expected, thanks sooooooo much for your help!  I tried to award you the bounty and it said "You may award your bounty in 21 hours." so you will get the bounty tomorrow, thanks again for all your help!